# Torrenting in a local network

Tags: networking, protocols, p2p, bittorrent

If a few people are torrenting the same file in a local network (a computer lab, for example), on different computers, will they be able to download faster?

In other words, is peer selection distance dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peer selection is speed dependent, however LAN speed is almost always higher than for external peers,  so it's unlikely to cause problems.

Use *Local Peer Discovery*, otherwise it can be problematic for the local peers to discover each other. If they use a external tracker and are behind a NAT, the NAT/router needs to support *hair pinning* to get it to work.